# Ext js 4:multiple grids showing different records from the same store

Tags: extjs4.1

I have a Json data store which contains the following records

```
{"resultList":[ 
{"type":"subscriber",
    "subrecord1":[{"dateVal":1390475422000,"typeId":0,"name":"abcd"},
              {"dateVal":1390475422567,"typeId":1,"name":"kdjjd"}],
    "subrecord2":[{"messageDate":1390475489899,"typeId":0,"location":"delhi"},
              {"messageDate":1390485422567,"typeId":1,"location":"pune"},
              {"messageDate":1390475498901,"typeId":1,"location":"mumbai"}] 

            }],"success":true,"total":1,"validationErrors":false}
```

Now i want to show subrecord1 in one grid and subrecored2 in another grid.
Grid1 contains columns 'dateVal','typeId', and 'name'.
Grid2 contains coulmns 'messageDate','typeId', and 'location'.

How can i do this from the same store?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you setup 2 stores with different readers that look at the [root](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Json-cfg-root) of the data differently. You can have each fetch its own data or have one fetch the data and the other load data from the first upon it's load completion.